# Create Event handler when hard_timeout value is expired

Tags: sdn, mininet, pox

In POX Controller, can I create an event listener that will be raised when a `hard_timeout` value is expired? Suppose I installed a `flow_mod` of `hard_timeout`= 10. After 10 seconds, my listener should be able to capture an event raised from this expiration. The reason of my question is that I want to activate a function only after a specific flow rule is expired.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can listen the event from the topology module for a flow removal

```
core.openflow.addListenerByName("FlowRemoved", self._handle_flow_removal)
```

then in the class method _handle_flow_removal you can get the reason

```
def _handle_flow_removal (self, event):
    """
    handler flow removed event here
    """
    print event.__dict__() # to get available info
```

In the event dict find the ofp key and extract the bool

```
ofp.reason == of.OFPRR_HARD_TIMEOUT:
```